# In Android, is it more efficient to use a 9patch or a layer-list with <shape> drawables?

Tags: android, nine-patch, layer-list

There will be many uses for this, but a perfect example is for creating drop shadows for views. I can either create a 9patch in Photoshop for the view background with the shadow, or I could create a layer-list drawable with multiple  items that does the same thing. But I don't know if one of those methods will use less resources at runtime. I don't care about the file sizes or the disk space usage (which would obviously be bigger with 9patch files). But I definitely care about the memory usage. and I want the app to run very smoothly on low end and older Android devices.

Comment: layer-list is just a container,  how much memory it uses depends on Drawables it holds,  but i dont know what you want to put in there

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer -- I just modified the question to clarify the the layer-list would use several <shape> items to make it look like a shadow.

Comment: if you dont want to use nine patch drawables but still want to see nice blurred shadow (which cannot be done by using xml based shapes) just extend Drawable and do your drawing in draw() method

Comment: That's not my concern. I just want to know which is more efficient at runtime. I don't care about the work involved on my end

Comment: the most efficient at runtime is a custom Drawable class since you have a fuul control over what (and how) is drawn

Comment: That's not an answer to my question, and a pretty useless comment as well. You can't make a new drawable class for every drawable in the app, and if you want to leave an answer, do it properly so I can downvote it for the useless info that it is

Comment: quote:  "I just want to know which is more efficient at runtime. I don't care about the work involved on my end", so my comment answers your concern: use a custom Drawable class,  that way you have full control on what you are drawing, i dont see why you see it useless

Comment: Because creating 200+ drawable classes for what would normally be drawable resources couldn't possibly be more efficient at runtime. And the question was which of the 2 options I asked about was more efficient. And if you don't know, you don't need to waste my time with useless comments about something completely unrelated to the question that was asked

Comment: the thing is that i know but if you are not listening so, yes, i won't waste my time with talking to you, good luck then